# Call an Activity after returning to main activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a main activity which is the main menu for my game - Also a second activity: the game itself. After the player finishes a game session they are then returned to the main menu - I want to call a method when they return to the main menu. How would I implement this?

Code for starting the game:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InGame.class);
            finish();
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Code for returning to the main menu:

```
public void returnMainMenu()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(InGame.this, MainActivity.class);
    InGame.this.startActivity(intentMain);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `startActivityForResult()` to go the game activity from the main activity. Also, do not finish the main activity, because the idea is to come back to it, and not create a new instance of it when you are coming back.

To return to the main menu, you should simply call `finish()` to kill the second activity and go back to the main activity. This will invoke `onActivityResult()` in the main activity.

To start the InGame Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InGame.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

To return to main menu,

```
public void returnMainMenu(){
    InGame.this.finish();
}
```

This invokes

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // your logic here 
    }
}
```

Read this **[Android documentation here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)** for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Though this is the right answer, an example of utilizing startActivityForResult would make this far more useful for other users.

Comment: Thanks!, I will attempt to implement this now

Comment: @zgc7009 : Agreed! Thanks for the suggestion. Have updated the answer with code and documentation! :)